# Cosmos DB failover with MongoDB.Driver library

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have an application which is using the MongoDB.Driver library (2.7.3) to connect to CosmosDB on Azure. The Cosmos account is set to replicate to a secondary in another region for disaster recovery. An issue I'm running into is that when we failover the Cosmos account, we lose connectivity and get the following error when we write data:

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
>   : "Automatic", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Connected", Servers : [{
>   ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
>   "Unspecified/myCosmosAccount.documents.azure.com:10255" }",
>   EndPoint: "Unspecified/myCosmosAccount.documents.azure.com:10255",
>   State: "Connected", Type: "ReplicaSetOther", Tags: "{ region : North
>   Europe }", WireVersionRange: "[0, 2]" }] }

I know it's possible to specify multiple servers in the MongoDB Connection String, however I'm not clear on how this can be achieved with Cosmos DB which only has a single endpoint for the account. My current connection string is this:

```
mongodb://myCosmosAccount:Key@myCosmosAccount.documents.azure.com:10255/myCosmosDatabase?ssl=true
```

Is this possible to do using this library, or do I need to switch to using the Cosmos DB SDK to improve Disaster Recovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8cdf09af-ff75-4c9b-8eb4-179464e04018/azure-cosmos-db-breaks-during-manual-failover?forum=azurecosmosdb

I needed to add: `replicaSet=globaldb` to the end of my connection string, so it now looks like this:

```
mongodb://myCosmosAccount:Key@myCosmosAccount.documents.azure.com:10255/myCosmosDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb
```